# EditText resize automatic depending screen programmatically

Tags: android, button, resize

I don't know how can I set the automatic resize(button,edittext) depending the screen smartphone(Android).

How can I set this automatic resize?(not with xml)

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

This is the code for a view:

```
View view_instance = (View)findViewById(R.id.nutrition_bar_filled);
LayoutParams params=view_instance.getLayoutParams();
params.width=LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
view_instance.setLayoutParams(params);
```

You can adapt them to a button, edittext, ...

Comment: But if you want the 80%screen? or this is a bad question? a little smaller than wrap content

Comment: Put wrap content and create fixed layout margins for example.